# How to get distinct count for larger column size in Progress-OpenEdge 12.2 query?

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I'm getting ERROR **[OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Insufficient Memory. Memory allocation failed at 751 in Z:/vobs_sql/sql/src/rds/psr_bld1.cxx. Contact Progress Technical Support**.

If I execute query to get **Distinct count** who's **column size** is **varchar(264)** for **MonthQuota** column.

[image: Data And Query Image]

Query which I have executed

> SELECT **COUNT(distinct MonthQuota)** AS distincto **FROM PUB.Salesrep** WHERE MonthQuota is NOT NULL;

Error: [image: Error Image]

So, Is there any solution for getting **Distinct count** for **varchar size** more than **264**.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Progress Technical Support as the error indicates?

Comment: yes. waiting for there reply.

Comment: openEdge version 12.2

Comment: You seem to be using the sports2020 database, but in that database the MonthQuota field is an integer with an extent - ie an array, when viewed as a character it shows as value;value;value;value